# how do i execute mongodb-compass pipeline code under documents tab

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, mongodb-compass

Is it possible to execute MongoDB Compass pipeline code (under aggregations tab )  in the Documents tab?
I have tried putting:

```
[{$group: {
 _id: {
  api: '$api'
 },
 count: {
  $sum: 1
 }
}}]
```

and

```
aggregate([{$group: {
 _id: {
  api: '$api'
 },
 count: {
  $sum: 1
 }
}}])
```

Comment: No, in the document tab it's only a filter (for find) or you can expand the box and get access to the sort and project. 
You can execute the command at the bottom though in mongosh that is available at the very bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks that explains , its sad that I cannot export pipeline output into a CSV only the filter commands. So now I have to find a way pipe that output into a CSV format.

Comment: One simple solution would be to create a view (which takes a pipeline as input) and then use `mongoexport --type csv` to export in CSV format.